# Huggingface pre trained bert model is not working

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I have pre-trained a bert model with custom corpus then got vocab file, checkpoints, model.bin, tfrecords, etc.

Then I loaded the model as below :

```py
# Load pre-trained model (weights)
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('/content/drive/My Drive/Anirban_test_pytorch')
```

But when I am trying to use the model for any task (like q and a, prediction of mask word etc.) then getti9ng below error

```py
from transformers import pipeline
nlp = pipeline("fill-mask", model="model")
nlp(f"This is the best thing I've {nlp.tokenizer.mask_token} in my life.")
```

ERROR:

OSError: Can't load config for 'model'. Make sure that:

- 'model' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'
- or 'model' is the correct path to a directory containing a config.json file

Can you please help me?

Comment: The issue is pretty simple. You have a variable called `model` but you use an unnamed string with the value `model` for your pipeline. That means, remove the quotes and it will work `nlp = pipeline("fill-mask", model=model)`. But keep in mind that your model produces only vector presentations of your input sequence and doesn't possess trained output layers.

Comment: @cronoik thanks! But I am getting below error now:

Comment: Exception: Impossible to guess which tokenizer to use. Please provided a PretrainedTokenizer class or a path/identifier to a pretrained tokenizer.

Comment: Have you trained your own tokenizer or did you use a pretrained tokenizer? `t=BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(....)` and `nlp = pipeline("fill-mask", model=model, tokenizer=t )`

Comment: @cronoik is the Tokenizer trained along with the model in the Trainer?

Comment: A tokenizer is just an object that splits strings into tokens and matches them with the corresponding id (an integer). There is nothing that can be trained except of extending the vocabulary. @Contestosis